# Automatic Proxy Configuration

Tags: internet-explorer, configuration, proxy

I have a PAC file on my server with the following code:

```
   function FindProxyForURL(url, host) { return "PROXY proxy.example.com:8080; DIRECT"; }
```

According to the WIKI page here - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_auto-config, this means that "should this proxy fail to respond, the browser contacts the website directly, without using a proxy."

I have tested this in Firefox and Chrome and if the proxy server is down it still seems to work. However in IE9, if the proxy server is down, websites fail to load? It seems that IE is not contacting sites directly if the proxy is down, something which is not an issue with Firefox or Chrome.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1):

I would think that IE does not support multiple proxies. Even underlying Windows libraries such as WinHTTP which has the best auto-proxy support (compared to WinInet) does not support multiple proxies:

> WinHTTP does not currently support proxy configurations that specify
>   more than one proxy server.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383157(v=VS.85).aspx

You could change your PAC file to be a dynamic script that checks to see if the proxy server is responding every X minutes. If the server is down it would respond with DIRECT, otherwise it would respond with your normal script.

Answer (score -1):

May be an IE bug. It is still in BETA